# Sorting people given who is shorter

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

So I have a Person class which contains a Person's name (string) and  the name of the Person who is the previous person in a row. We already know that "Peter" is the first in the row, he doesnt have previous person. I want to give them a number which displays the order.

```
class Person{

    private String name;
    private int number;
    private String previousName;
    //getters and setters... 
}
```

```
public class Main {
    private static Person[] persons; //filled up with names...
      for(int i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<persons.length; j++){
                if(persons[i].getName().equals(persons[j].getPreviousName())){
                    persons[j].setNumber(persons[i].getNumber()+1);
                    break;
                }

            }
          }
}
```

input:

```
format: name ; previous person's name:
Peter (first in the row)//
Dave;Joseph//
Samuel;Steve//
Joseph;Peter//
Steve;Dave
```

result should be:

```
Peter - 1
Joseph - 2
Dave - 3
Steve - 4
Samuel - 5
```

my result:

```
Peter 1
Dave 3
Samuel 2
Joseph 2
Steve 1
```

Comment: You mention "height" in the title, but nothing in your code refers to height. Can you clarify what the person's height has to do with your question?

Comment: How would you number the people by hand? If I gave you the names like you type them into your program, how would you go about numbering them?

Comment: The row is based on "height", the actual height of the person doesnt matter, only the position in the row.

Comment: So when you input `Dave;Joseph` this means that Joseph is shorter (taller) than Dave?

Comment: Exactly. I mean that.

Comment: One skill you need to develop as a programmer is determining what details matter in solving a problem and what ones don't. In this case, the concept of a person's height is just a background detail from the story that gives the problem you are trying to solve. It is actually irrelevant to how you write the code. The important part here is that you have input which tells you which person goes after another person. So back to my previous question: given the list of "before;after" from the input, how would you go about sorting the names by hand? Work through the example and then try...

Comment: ... to describe the steps to take **in words**.

Comment: Your for loop if statement evauluates whether or not the current i index of persons is equal to the index beforehand, is this correct?  If so, how exactly are you getting the previousName.  Plus are you aware that your 2nd nested for loop is going to run 3 times?  And I think what he means about the height is the **heiarchy**, not the actual height.

Comment: @Thomas I suspect that this problem came with a story about sorting men by their height. This detail is just background flavor and not relevant to the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but this should work. The basic idea is to find the first person in list. And then iterate over the list finding the next person having the previous name as current name. Not a very optimized solution definitely but can be improved!

```
//Find the first person in list, assuming first person has no previous name
int currentPerson = 0;
for (int i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
    if (persons[i].getPreviousName().equals("")){
        currentPerson = i;
        break;
    }
}
persons[currentPerson].setNumber(1);
int count = 1;

//loop until you number every person
while (count < persons.length){
    //find the next person after current person
    for (int i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
        if (persons[i].getPreviousName().equals(persons[currentPerson].getName())){
            persons[currentPerson].setNumber(count++);
            currentPerson = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```